# How to write something in Latex Beamer Ilmenau dark blue top bar

Tags: beamer, graphics, urls

I'm trying to make a latex presentation using beamer and ilmenau. I wanna include an image and have its source in the dark blue bar below the very dark blue bar that shows how far into the presentation you are. Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}[]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\mode <presentation>{
    \usetheme{Ilmenau}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\title[Short title]{extremly long and complicated title} 

\author[ĺastname]{firstname}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{long title}
        
        ,,Scientific title goes here ''
        
        
        \begin{center}
            \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{greenliquid}
                
            \end{figure}
            
        \end{center}
        
        

        
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It currently looks something like this:
[image]

And I wanna have the image source displayed here:
[image: use Linux]

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second blue bar is for the subsection title. If you want to show some text there, you could use a subsection outside of the frame.

Some other comments about your code:

- you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` -- that's the default since a couple of years
- no need to load `grpahics/x`, beamer loads it for you
- figures are centred by default in beamer, no need for `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}[]

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
\mode <presentation>{
    \usetheme{Ilmenau}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\title[Short title]{extremly long and complicated title} 

\author[ĺastname]{firstname}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Einleitung}
    \subsection{Image source: the cool book where I got the image from}
    \begin{frame}{long title}
        
        ,,Scientific title goes here ''
        
        
%        \begin{center}
            \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
                
            \end{figure}
            
%        \end{center}
        
        

        
\end{frame}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
next frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]